# How to save MakeNetCDFTableView output?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, table, netcdf

I was trying to extract the time-series data from the netcdf using grid points (lat/long) by `MakeNetCDFTableView`. I have more than 100 grid points and I want to extract the data from the netcdf file. 
I was trying the following pyscript, but couldn't save the output table.

Could you please help me fix my problem?

```
#Import system modules
import arcpy

# Set local variables
inNetCDFFile = "F:/VIC_FORCINGS/7071.nc"
variable = "prec"
outTableView = "F:/VIC_FORCINGS/precipm"
rowDimension = "time"
dimensionValue = "64;-146"
valueSelectionMethod = ""

# Execute MakeNetCDFTableView
arcpy.MakeNetCDFTableView_md(inNetCDFFile, variable, outTableView, rowDimension, dimensionValue,valueSelectionMethod)

outTable = arcpy.CopyRows_management(outTableView)
print
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  the [Copy Rows Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0017000000n4000000) to save the table view.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am able to save the table. The problem is still I couldn't save in txt or csv or xls file. The output is gdf. The other issues I found is the value are not changing for different grid points. I couldn't figureout why. I may have problem when giving the dimension value. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Abraham Your question makes no mention of outputting to *.txt or *.csv, and you seem to have incorporated this answer into your question.  Consequently, I think you should consider accepting this answer and then researching/asking the new question separately.